# save values in database using django

Tags: python, database, django, error-handling

i have an custom form , whenever i fetch the form values to save in the database than it display an error ( applicationform() got an unexpected keyword argument 'job_title' ) and the values are not save in the table.

views.py :-

```
def applicationvalue(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

            getjobtitle = request.POST['jobtitle']


            getintable = applicationform(job_title=getjobtitle)
            getintable.save()

            print getjobtitle
            return HttpResponse(getintable)

    else:
        return render_to_response('registration/applicationform.html')
```

my form is :-

```
<form method="POST" action="#" class="form-horizontal" id="applicationform" name="appform">
<input type="text" id="u_jobtitle" class="input-xlarge" name="jobtitle" value=" " />
<button class="btn btn-gebo" type="submit" name="usubmit">Save changes</button>
```

whenever i fetch the values from form to save the values in table field " job_title " than it will display an error :-

applicationform() got an unexpected keyword argument 'job_title'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `input` field name to `job_title` in your html

```
<input name="job_title" type="text" id="u_jobtitle" class="input-xlarge" value=" " />
-------------^ changed
```

and then in view do

```
def applicationvalue(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    #Dont need this
    #getjobtitle = request.POST['jobtitle']
    #---------------------------Use request.POST
    getintable = applicationform(request.POST)
    getintable.save()

    print getjobtitle
    return HttpResponse(getintable)
  else:
    return render_to_response('registration/applicationform.html')
```

It will be better if you use same form to render html instead of hand coding it.

Answer (score 2):

The `applicationform` constructor should take the `request.POST` as argument. 
But it seems to me that you are not using django forms in the "right" way. I think that your view doesn't follow the django philosophy for using form.

In your case, you should have a model:

```
from django.db import models

class Application(models.Model):
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Based on this model, you can declare a ModelForm:

```
from django import forms
from .models import ApplicationModel

class ApplicationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ApplicationModel
        fields = ('job_title',)
```

Then you can use this form in your view

```
def applicationvalue(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = ApplicationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            #This is called when the form fields are ok and we can create the object
            application_object = form.save()

            return HttpResponse("Some HTML code") # or HttResponseRedirect("/any_url")

    else:
        form = ApplicationForm() 

    #This called when we need to display the form: get or error in form fields
    return render_to_response('registration/applicationform.html', {'form': form})
```

finally you should have a `registration/applicationform.html` template with something like:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
   <table>
      {{form.as_table}}
   </table>
   <input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

I hope it helps

Comment: You are really right about the way @Ranjeet and Rohan is using the form is absolutely not right.